# Rails: How do load/trigger a js.erb using the controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm not even sure how to ask this question in a way thats understandable.

Basically, I'd like to do some javascript using a js.erb after I save. I'm submitting the form using a regular javascript/coffee-script file (if all fields are filled in correctly, then the form is submitted, else the form does nothing & just displays errors).

Part of my coffee-script:

```
fieldCorrectResponse: (fields, response) ->
    if fields == correct
        $('#new_mail')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#mail_error').text('error while filling out form')
```

my mail controller:

```
def create
    @mail = Mail.new(mail_params)

    if @mail.save

      #PERFORM SOME JS USING A JS.ERB
    else
      render :new
    end
END
```

So I guess what I'm really is asking is, how would you call a js.erb in the controller?

---

Wrote the solution to my problem below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to render `js` and use `create.js.erb`.

Please try:

```
# MailsController
def create
    @mail = Mail.new(mail_params)

    if @mail.save
      respond_to do |format| 
        format.js
      end
    else
      render :new
    end
END
```

Then, implement your javascript in `app/views/mails/create.js.erb`.

Comment: I tried this already but am just getting redirected to `http://localhost:3000/mails` & getting a blank screen. My terminal says `Completed 406 Not Acceptable`.. I should also note that I'm submitting the form through another view

Answer (score 0):

"do some javascript" isn't terribly descriptive. are you wanting to return a JSON object from the create action, which can then be parsed by the success callback on your jquery? Or do you want to have a template that has javascript in it that gets called as a result of the save action?

vinod covered the second way. make sure you have your routes set up correctly.

if you want to return a parseable JSON object, then write

```
render json: { some: 'json objects', should: 'go here' }
```

Also, not knowing what "mails" are, if you're trying to send emails that should be done with action mailer, and probably done as a part of committing the main model to the database (if you're creating a user and also trying to send an email, have a method as part of user creation that sends out the email).

Comment: Hey Stuart, I'm trying to have a template that has javascript int it get called (js.erb file). The app actually has nothing to do with mailing, just learning rails. I usually have no problem calling a js.erb file but am not getting a `406 Not Acceptable`.. Since posting, I've found out that its a not so uncommon problem (http://hybernaut.github.io/blog/2012/03/22/rails-controller-returning-406-not-acceptable/)... I maybe should just start a new thread/post.. Thx